# Cannot setState after receiving user from service provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am receiving the user properly from my provider but for some reason the state does not change with the user object.

This returns the user object properly:

```
console.log(receivedUser);
```

However, after I try to do this, there's no object:

```
setUser(receivedUser);
  console.log(user);
```

What seems to be the issue here guys? Why doesn't the state change at all?

Full code:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({})

// this prevents this providerValue changing unless value or setValue changes
const providerValue = useMemo(() => ({user, setUser}), [user, setUser])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUser(){
    const receivedUser = await AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    if (receivedUser) {
      // console.log(receivedUser);
      setUser(receivedUser);
      console.log(user);
    } else {
      console.log("user not logged in");
    }
    }
    fetchUser();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updation of state is asynchronous. you need to use useEffect to console out the value of state. A seperate useEffect can be created which would be triggered every time the user in the state changes

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({})

// this prevents this providerValue changing unless value or setValue changes
const providerValue = useMemo(() => ({user, setUser}), [user, setUser])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUser(){
    const receivedUser = await AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    if (receivedUser) {
      // console.log(receivedUser);
      setUser(receivedUser);
      console.log(user);
    } else {
      console.log("user not logged in");
    }
    }
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log('user',user)
    }, [user])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that, first `setUser` is an `async`.
You have to understand the life circle of `useState`

Will give you an example how to handle this right and wrong..

see below to example..

```js
const [text, setText] = useState("default");


useEffect(() => {
  setText("test");

  console.log(text) // this will print defult
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(text) // this will print test
}, [text])
```

Comment: This sends 1 request per second and I don't want 1000 requests every second when I have users in the application, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You say that but you still market @Erik Answer as the right answer? which is the same as mine:)

Answer (score 0):

setUser it's kind of asynchronous function. State of user doesn't change immediately after you call this function. If you want to handle when user state change add another on useEffect which checking if user state change:

```
useEffect( () => {
   /* this will be call any time user state change */
   if ( user ) {
       /* do something if user was fetched */
   }
}, [user])
```